# Arcgis Javascript Api - Show WebMap by Id

Tags: javascript, arcgis

The code below creates a new map and adds a layer. I dont want to create a new map i want to add a webmap by an id. How can I load a webmap with my id instead? Id like to load my webmap instead of creating a new map:

```
    var initExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({ "xmin": -89.26, "ymin": 15.85, "xmax": -88.13, "ymax": 18.75, "spatialReference": { "wkid": 5326 } });


    map = new esri.Map("map",{
        extent:esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(initExtent),
        wrapAround180 : true
    });

    dojo.connect(map, 'onLoad', onMapLoaded);

    //Add the topographic layer to the map. View the ArcGIS Online site for services http://arcgisonline/home/search.html?t=content&f=typekeywords:service
    var basemap = new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Topo_Map/MapServer", {
            id: 'basemap'
        });
    currentBasemap = basemap;
    map.addLayer(currentBasemap);

    //Add some basic layers
    var rivers = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("http://services.arcgis.com/LxfKOYkTamDQYlsa/arcgis/rest/services/PollingStations2015/FeatureServer/0", {
        mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
        outFields: ["*"]
    });


    map.addLayers([rivers]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `createMap` function in [`esri.arcgis.utils`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.arcgis.utils-amd.html). [This sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ags_createwebmapid.html) shows how. Here is the most relevant code:

```
arcgisUtils.createMap("4778fee6371d4e83a22786029f30c7e1","map")
.then(function(response) {
  var map = response.map;
  //The map is loaded, so you can directly call your onMapLoaded function...
  onMapLoaded(map);      
});
```

You'll need to include `"esri/arcgis/utils"` as `arcgisUtils` in your list of required modules.

Comment: That sample doesn't run on my browser. Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried it with chrome and Firefox as well as Internet Explorer. It doesnt load the map. I get no errors and i am using my webap id with no luck. Do you know if something is wrong with the sample you linked to?

Comment: The sample is fine. You should run the app in Chrome with the developer console showing (Ctrl-Shift-J). The Console tab will show any error messages or warnings. The Network tab will show the network requests being made and help you find which items your machine can't find.

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/98f90d001fef48bf8998af2a8b7839ec?f=json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.k @ init.js:152b.xhr @ init.js:185b.xhrGet @ init.js:185x @

Comment: Clearly, file://www.arcgis.com doesn't exist. You must be loading your page as a file:// URL in the browser. Try putting it on a web server so you can load it through http:// or https:// instead of file:// . And check out the actual live sample at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/ags_createwebmapid/ to verify that it works.

Comment: Hmm. I put it on a server and now im getting : The XMLHttpRequest progress event property 'position' is deprecated. Please use 'loaded' instead.   http://mercadobelize.com/webmap.html

Comment: Thanks for putting it on a public server. That's very helpful. The message you see is just a warning. The real problem is that the browser can't find css/layout.css. You can either 1) download http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/ags_createwebmapid/css/layout.css and put it on your web server in a css directory that is in the same directory as your HTML file or 2) change "css/layout.css" to "http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/ags_createwebmapid/css/layout.css" in your web page. Then it will work.